# HTML responsive link based on device

Tags: javascript, html, ios, twitter, responsive-design

I have a responsive website (mobile first design) that has a contact page with links to social media pages, email, etc.

I would like for these links to utilize the "deep link" functionality when opened from an iPhone (eg. twitter://user?screen_name=name would open the twitter profile in the native app) but then I also need them to be able to open the http://twitter.com/name when on a desktop or when deep link is not available.

What is the best approach to this?

Comment: I'm afraid you'd have to do browser detection, afaik there is no way to feature detect support for app protocols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the links by javascript, there you can check which device is connected using the `navigator.userAgent` property.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would add that if the presentation is different, add the browser class to the body and format the link on css:

```
body.mobile a{ color: red; text-overflow: ellipsis;}
body.desktop a{ color: blue; }
```